# Lightning Component - single resource not downloaded

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, security, static-resources

I have a VF page with custom css referencing some images in resources like this:
background-image: url(/resource/1265000000000/someImage);

I created a new dev sandbox and the page looks like expected.
I expose the page in a lightning component via an Iframe in communities - this particular resource can not be downloaded images are missing.
JS console logs show 
https://xxxxxxx.csxx.force.com/resource/1265000000000/someImage 503 (Service Unavailable)

On other sandbox the Iframe-community config works fine
What could be the reason? I  don't see difference between the 2 dev sandboxes

Answer (score 1):

If your community is mycommunity.com/support
you need to use "/support/resource/13237000/resourcename"